# How to drill holes into stone steps to install iron railing?

Tags: stairs, railing

I have some steps in my backyard that I would like to add a metal railing to as they get quite slippery in winter. The steps were installed by the former owner and as far as I can tell they are made of some type of stone.

I planned to get an iron railing fabricate, drill a hole in the steps for each leg, and set it in place using hydraulic cement. My main question is what type of drill and bit I'd want to use for drilling into the stone and are there any strategies I should utilize to do this right and not cause unintended damage?

Also open to any suggestions if anything about my approach seems incorrect.

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/0R8niKl)

Comment: Anchoring cement, not hydraulic cement, is the product to use. Be sure to overfill the holes a little so that water doesn't accumulate at the base of your posts. They'll rust through in no time with a pool of water there.

Comment: Would you consider mounting the railing, not to the steps, but in the ground next to them? The leaves make it hard to tell, but if you have access to the ground on the left of the steps (while facing up) it might be quite a bit easier. And would also not risk damaging the steps.

Comment: @DougDeden I'm not opposed to installing the railing in the ground, I considered this option as well. There would be dirt on both sides I could install in. Do you have more info on how I would do that? What would I want to use to make the hole in the ground? Also I assume I would need longer legs on the railing as they'd have to go further into the ground than the stone.

Comment: That's not really my area of expertise. I was just throwing it out there as an alternative. I could imagine just digging the dirt out with a shovel, setting the railing pipe in, and backfilling. But yes, you'd have to go pretty deep to make it solid. I would have guessed about 30 inches (750 mm) based on how deep fenceposts are usually placed. This site -- https://www.zottolafab.com/2006/09/18/installation-in-ground/ -- just has you go down a foot and pour concrete around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those appear to be slate of some sort.

Slate fractures/splits/delaminates rather easily, so I would suggest using a diamond core drill to smoothly bore a hole rather than a typical masonry bit and hammer-drill apprach, which might make a good deal more damage along with the hole.

Diamond core drills can commonly be rented from a tool rental company, as they are a bit expensive to buy for most people's amount of use.

Comment: You can buy a diamond hole saw that can be used in a standard drill, for not too much money.  But I think the proper tool depends on what kind of railing the OP intends to install, and what kind of base it has.